# Define direction for type @relation with from and to for the same type

Tags: graphql, grandstack

Is it possible to define directions for a type @relation with from and to for the same type in neo4j-graphql?

```
Type Relation @relation(name: "RELATION") {
  from: Node!
  to: Node!
  property: Int!
}

Type Node {
  id: ID!
  in: [Relation] 
  out: [Relation]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-java#relationship-on-types

For Java, kudos to Michael Hunger.